# HC-02 Bluetooth module not visible

Tags: serial, bluetooth

I am trying to connect to my robot car with the HC-02 module. The problem is that the module is visible on my phone only while the arduino uno board is connected to my laptop. At this point I can pair my phone with the module, but I can't controll the car. When I disconnect the car from my laptop and turn it on, HC-02 is not visible anymore. It's blinking fast which means it should be available for connecting. I cant access the AT mode and I don't know what to do anymore. Has anyone had problems with this. 
My phone is Android, I also tried with another one and still not working.

I also removed arduino uno from the car, I connected only the Bluetooth module. I can see HC-02 when Arduino is connected to the PC with the USB cable. But when I disconnect it from the PC and power it with the battery it disappears from available devices.

[image]

Comment: can you share your code and schematic here.

Comment: I added the code. I also explained it a little more

Comment: Try another serial using SOFTWARE Serial Library for ardunio for HC-02. Then connect arduino to your laptop and try to control your car and attach your full code here. Copy Paste you code here.

Comment: I tried with your solution and it works, thanks. There is obviously problem with the RX0 and TX1 pins.